# Which Islam groups are for death by stoning after adultery, and does this apply to every follower within the group in question?

Tags: punishment, adultery, rajm

I saw a video about one or two years ago which i cannot seem to find at the moment, in which there was a muslim speaker preaching about Islam to a bunch of children, whom were also obviously muslims. In the video the speaker asked questions, and this was one of them (Probably not accurate word for word):

"The Qu'ran tells us death by stoning is the right punishment for adultery, so whom of you in this room think that this is the right punishment for adulterers?"

Every child in the room as far as I could tell were pointing their arm to the ceiling.

Does every child in the room want to kill adulterers with stones, or am I missing something here?

Is there a specific group/groups of islam followers who would be more primitive and violent like this than other groups?

Comment: Is it a fair summary of the question that you ask whether in islam, stoning to death is the punishment for adultery, and how well this opinion is subscribed to?

Comment: Yes I guess that is the main part of the question I'm asking. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: No and I've been looking for the video forever without being able to find it unfortunately. Yes, the question was asked (in a very bias-provoking and aggressive way) and almost every child in the room raised their hand affirmatively as if they actually wanted to stone adulterers because that was what the Quran said to do; the "right thing" to do.

Comment: @Envayo Correct, and the kids have given their answer already, however the question posed was not whether that was what they actually answered (I could see that in the video), but whether I might have misunderstood. I realize this might be impossible to tell without the original video, but I was looking for someone who might understand the eventual misconception (which is a lot to ask for without providing the video) or might have seen the video to answer. However, that was a blatant "yes" by the children to a blatantly obvious question posed about stoning adulterers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stoning an adulterer is the universally accepted legal punishment among the scholars of sunni islam (see e.g. [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/20824)), and I think among shia scholars as well. The material law (i.e. what is the punishment and what constitutes adultery) is quite clear; penetrative sex while married with someone you are not married to constitutes adultery, and the punishment is being stoned to death.

---

The procedural law, i.e. questions of burden of proof etc., is a different matter. To prove adultery via eye-witnesses would require four adult male muslim witnesses of good standing who actually saw the penis enter the vagina. I have also seen the opinion that the husband who finds his wife having sex with another man could [swear four times](https://islamqa.info/en/101771) (this is called "li'aan"; search "should make him swear four times by Allaah" on that page) to replace the four witnesses in order to match the burden of proof; the so-accused wife can herself swear four times to avert stoning. Proving her husband has been adulterous by means of li'aan is not accepted from the wife according to that link. I do not know how widespread li'aan is, but the source for it, [24:6-24:9](http://www.usc.edu/org/cmje/religious-texts/quran/verses/024-qmt.php#024.006), suggests that it is probably widely accepted. Another way of meeting the burden of proof is a confession by the offender.

---

To gauge the popular support for this punishment in the general population, the [pew research center](http://www.pewglobal.org/2010/12/02/muslims-around-the-world-divided-on-hamas-and-hezbollah/#support-for-severe-laws) polled the populations of majority-muslim countries; with Turkey at 16% of the muslim population in support of stoning adulterers to death forming the least committed group, it seems like a very significant proportion of muslims worldwide is willing to support this punishment, at least by voicing that opinion in a poll. The question whether they would work towards implementing it, or tolerate it once it is enacted into law, is not really answerable from that data, of course.

Comment: Why did you twist the IslamQA link (largely considered unreliable) by removing the part in which if the female does li'an she can avoid the hadd?

Comment: @G.Bach No, it's a matter of proof also, as the one who sweared proof would not reach the hudud level of evidence to carry out the hadd. It's important yet you left it. In general IslamQA is unreliable.

Comment: @G.Bach           OK . . .

Comment: Still no mention of the famous legal maxim that every Muslim jurist agreed on that "Ward off the Hudud by ambiguities" and no mention of other deterrents such as if a confessed adulterer/adulteress retracted his/her confession.

Comment: This is just the kind of answer I wanted. Thank you G. Bach for an informative and well written answer.

Comment: @Envayo I'm not aware of any legal manual or scholar of fiqh who interprets rajm as anything but stoning people to death. The meaning of stoning someone as a legal punishment is as clear as the meaning of hanging someone or drowning someone or shooting someone as legal punishments; it's understood without adding "to death". The punishment of stoning is derived from ahadith, some of which report that there used to be a Quranic verse that commanded stoning, the recital of which was later abrogated but the commandment of which was not; this mode of naskh is called "naskh al-tilawa duna al-hukm".

Comment: @Envayo The fuqaha are also largely in agreement that "witches", people having gay sex, and apostates deserve some form of death penalty (depending on their "crime"). Stoning adulterers does not look any more radical than any of those.

Comment: Shia'a Sunni and Ibadi agree on stoning for married fornicator.